# What's the proper name for the kind of rope switches you find in toys like teddy bears?

Tags: switches, identification

I'm looking for the right name of the switch or mechanism that is often found in older child toys like teddy bears. It's basically a rope which can be pulled at and when released the bear would 'say' something or sing or whatever.

I need this kind of switch to just close/open a contact and to re-wind the rope inside so it can be pulled again afterwards. What is it called and where can we find such switches / mechanisms?

Comment: Your description sounds like the old mechanical playback mechanisms.  You pulled the string which wound a spring to turn a mechanical record player.  It also rewound the string for the next pull.  No electronics, no batteries, no switches.  No rope.

Comment: It's called a [pull-string](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51p2u0QGzjL._AC_.jpg)

Comment: Also look for "pull cord recoil mechanism", commonly used to start small gas engines.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you described is not a switch. The pull strings in toy animals operate(d) a mechanical playback system - a sort of spring powered phonograph player.

There are switches with a pull string, though.

They are called ["pull switches."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_switch)

They look like this:

[image]

<sub>Image from [this Amazon page](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Switch-Universal-Ceiling-Replacement-Vintage/dp/B07VLQ4DNW)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Originally (1960s) toys of that kind (such as the Chatty Cathy doll) had a mechanical phonograph mechanism inside. Pulling the string wound a clockwork spring and releasing it allowed the disk to spin, producing a sound. No batteries or electronics at all. Image from [here](http://www.toyrepairs.co.uk/pulcord.htm)

[image]

The Toy Story movie franchise featured a character with an old-school pull-string on his back, so merchandise produced to capitalize on the movie incorporated a kind of fake pull-string mechanism with the string turning a spring-loaded pulley and operating a switch which triggered an electronic chip-on-board voice IC. Such modules do not appear to use a third-party switch, rather the switch mechanism is part of the module. Image from [here](https://youtu.be/gW7O4x-uzFE).

[image]

Of course you can purchase complete modules to manufacture toys, but not, as far as I know, the switch itself as a component.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I will end up 3D printing my own fake pull-string mechanism since it's kind of a special usecase. Thanks for the research and clarification.